# adding and removing class and preventig fadeTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created 3 links which when hovered over fade, I have also added a click event that when clicked adds the class 'active' and then i want to remove the class when clicked again. I have read a few posts that seem to suggest that removeClass come before addClass but im not sure why. Also when I click the link and the addClass is implemented I would also like to disable the fadeTo on this?

If anyone could explain each of these processes that would be great as Im trying to learn jQuery.

Code is here http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/FtUdN/

Answer (score 0):

## Click here to see a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rVhte/

```
$('#nav li a').toggle(

function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#nav li a").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');


}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('#nav li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(200, 0.5).end();
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(200, 1.0).end();
});


});
```

Edit: disabled mouseover events after a link is clicked

Comment: Why to stop fades? Disable the fades only on the 'clicked' element! And why not to use .stop() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the click:

```
        $('#nav li a').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('active')
        });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/FtUdN/3/

Comment: excuse my unknowledge, but What's the .end() here for?

Comment: @roXon, it finishes the animation, im not sure why its here tho... good question

Comment: @Neil be careful to finish animations with .end(), ;)  cause this prop. ends the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method. In your `hover` handlers, you can use the [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method to check if you should fade or not.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfvgyhn/FtUdN/13/

Comment: hi @Rfvgyhn when the link is clicked the active colour black is actually at the fade opacity? also what does if (!$this.hasClass("active")) mean?

Comment: @Rfvgyhn: You thought: $this.stop().fadeTo(200, 0.5);

Comment: @kyllle that means '' if --> this (#nav li a) --> has NOT class 'active'. And, killle, use the .stop() to 'queue false' fade animation.

Comment: thanks @roXon although when I add $this.stop() the clicked link remains as a faded black instead of 100% opacity?

Comment: @killle that is not due to .stop(), if you do NOT use stop and maniacally hover-unhover the link, the animation continues to fade-unfade. To stop this we use .stop() as I mentioned above.

Comment: thanks once again @roXon can you explain why the active link is inheriting the fadeTo opacity of 0.5 when clicked?

Comment: @kyllle Well, that's easy to explain. On click stops the previous HOVER state. And the link remain on the 0.5 opacity. Just restore this by modifying the 3th line of the click function with` $("a.active").fadeTo(0, 1.0).removeClass("active");`  Doing so you restored the 1.0 opacity!! right?

Comment: Sorry I left you hanging kyllle. roXon looks like he's covered your questions, but I have updated the fiddle based on your comments.